# Confusing error requesting semicolon (error C2143)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am using VS Professional 2013 and I am building a console application. One of my methods is determining string length from user input. I keep receiving a confusing error on line 5 of this method: that there is a missing semicolon (error C2143). No functions within the line require an extra semicolon to my knowledge. Also, I am intentionally not calling namespaces. The #include functions are replicated below and are stored in the header file.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <tchar.h> //Part of VS' implementation for applications. Can effectively be ignored. 
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::cout << "Enter your string: " << std::flush;
    std::string.getline(std::cin, s);
    const int size = s.length();
    std::cout << "The total number of characters entered is: " << size << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` has no member `getline`, so `std::string.getline(std::cin, s);` is illegal.

You want

```
std::getline(std::cin, s);
```

Comment: Oops, you're right, there's a special rule that forbids it [dcl.dcl]/3. clang++ only emits a warning.